# alexa request with undefined namespace

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I try to connect my Lambda function Amazon Alexa Skill, but fail in the beginning of discovery.

In Alexa App, I enable and link my Skill using LWA account.
When I say, "Alexa, discover smart devices", I can see my lambda log with request error.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'namespace' of undefined`

What's condition to let Alexa send me request header with namespace "Alexa.ConnectedHome.Discovery"?

Answer (score 1):

I can receive Request with content finally.
The problem is coming from skill Payload version option.
I chose V3 (preferred) option before, then nothing received.
After I switched to V2 (legacy), Discover handler could be triggered.

Comment: This fixed it for me too... Did you ever figure out how to use V3?

Answer (score 1):

V3 sends `[Alexa.Discovery][1]` instead of Alexa.ConnectedHome.Discover. Your skill needs to handle Discovery directive(namespace:Alexa.Discovery and name:Discovery) and send Discover response(namespace:Alexa.Discovery and name:Discover.Response). If you need to migrate your skill from v2 to v3, I'd recommend checking https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/smart-home-skill-migration-guide.html for more details.